# Swift addition does not work if it's placed after Nil-Coalescing operator

Tags: ios, swift

I understand that the core issue could be related to system not understanding the precedence but I am not 100% sure. Does anyone understand why the following code set value of q = 1.

```
var i: Int? = 1
var v = 2
let q = i ?? 0 + v
```

when I change the last line to:

```
let q = (i ?? 0) + v
```

then it works well. I understand that + has higher precedence than ?? according to [this source](https://www.programiz.com/swift-programming/operator-precedence-associativity#:%7E:text=Operator%20precedence%20is%20a%20collection,order%20called%20as%20operator%20precedence.) but it doesn't make sense in this equation

Comment: You seem to have found the answer already. "+ has higher precedence than ??". What are you confused about?

Comment: Yea, I think I just wanted to verify if I was thinking in the right direction here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon confirmation, I am now satisfied that it's due to + having higher precedence over ??. Putting code inside () did the trick for me to control the precedence in calculation